# Multiple Node Apps on one server, Nginx serving just one site

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, server, port

I have a server that I want to use to host two node apps, yet no matter what I do, my second domain is serving domain1.com.

I want the node apps to be on domain1.com and one on domain2.com.

Here are the configurations:

domain1.com

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name www.domain1.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}



server {

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name www.domain1.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_prams;
        }

}
```

domain2.com

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name www.domain2.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}



server {

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name www.domain2.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002/;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_prams;
        }

}
```

Here is the express setup for domain2.com

```
let port = (3002);
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
*/

var server = http.createServer(app);
```

As you can see, I have set the ports in the nginx server blocks, but only domain1.com is being served. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Just as a test, try setting the server name that isn't working to the catch-all "_".

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to test your configuration and see exactly which files nginx is reading.

Comment: @Alan so just set the server name to `server_name _;`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Hmm, it doesn't seem to be reading the Domain2 file at all

Comment: I don't know how your configuration files are organised, but on some OSs they are placed in `sites-available` and symlinked to `sites-enabled`. In the top level configuration file called `nginx.conf`, you should see the `include` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for the reply, I see this in the server block in conf.d 
`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` 

I have both the sites-available and enabled folder and have created the system links for both. The domain1.com website has been up for about 6 months already.

Comment: Whoops. System link was red so I removed it and made a new one using sudo. nginx -T now shows the domain2 configuration file but my domain is still redirecting.

Comment: @MoeSmith right `server_name _;` and then maybe try commenting out the config for domain that *is* working and see if the one that isn't working works. That will probably clue you in to whether there is a conflict between the two that is causing the problem, or if it is just the one config that isn't working if that makes sense.

Comment: @Alan I tried disabling the domain1.com config and I just got a 502 error when visiting domain2.com. I set up the catchall and even changed the port to 8080 yet it's still serving the domain1.com content